# SQL: Fetch value from XMLTYPE

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

Could you tell me how to print both vendor site values 1254 and 90.
It can be either 2 or 3 or more sites, so I need to print all the sites.

DECLARE

```
vendor_xml xmltype :=  
    xmltype( 
        '<VENDORLIST> 
            <VENDOR> 
                <VENDOR_NAME>Testvendorname</VENDOR_NAME> 
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>1254</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>90</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>                   
            </VENDOR> 
        </VENDORLIST>'); 

vendor_name varchar2(100); 
vendor_site number(5); 

cursor cur_sites
IS
SELECT XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('/VENDORLIST/VENDOR/SITE/ERPSITEID' PASSING vendor_xml RETURNING CONTENT) AS number(5)) "REFERENCE"
FROM dual;
```

BEGIN

```
FOR i IN cur_sites
LOOP  
   dbms_output.put_line('v-site    :  ' || i.reference); 
END LOOP;
```

END;

Could you advice.

Thanks
Praj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE
    vendor_xml   XMLTYPE := xmltype(
        '<VENDORLIST> 
            <VENDOR> 
                <VENDOR_NAME>Testvendorname</VENDOR_NAME> 
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>1254</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>90</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
            </VENDOR> 
        </VENDORLIST>');

    CURSOR cur 
    IS 
    SELECT vendor_site
      FROM  XMLTABLE ( '*/VENDOR/SITE' 
            PASSING vendor_xml 
            COLUMNS vendor_site NUMBER PATH 'ERPSITEID' );

BEGIN
    FOR i IN cur LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('v-site: ' || i.vendor_site);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If you want to take into account the master-detail relationship, you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE
    vendor_xml   XMLTYPE := xmltype(
        '<VENDORLIST> 
            <VENDOR> 
                <VENDOR_NAME>Testvendorname</VENDOR_NAME> 
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>1254</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>90</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
            </VENDOR> 
            <VENDOR> 
                <VENDOR_NAME>Vendor2</VENDOR_NAME> 
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>4711</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
                <SITE>
                   <ERPSITEID>123</ERPSITEID>
                </SITE>
            </VENDOR> 
        </VENDORLIST>');

    CURSOR cur 
    IS 
    SELECT v.vendor_name, vs.vendor_site
      FROM  XMLTABLE ( '*/VENDOR' 
            PASSING vendor_xml 
            COLUMNS vendor_name VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'VENDOR_NAME'
                  , vendor_sites XMLTYPE PATH 'SITE') v
          , XMLTABLE ( '*' 
            PASSING v.vendor_sites 
            COLUMNS vendor_site NUMBER PATH 'ERPSITEID' ) vs
    ;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN cur LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('v-name: ' || i.vendor_name || ', v-site: ' || i.vendor_site);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```